# ng-click adding and removing classes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I trying to create a click function which has two states `add` and `added` both states are visible in my solution, however i only want one state to show at a time.  thus far my logic is to structure it in the following way. demo I have noticed when i click on the item the class is activated how i am unable to remove the class. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cAtniSUMpodZx5skAbPR?p=preview)

```
<div ng-repeat= "fav in fav">
   <div ng-click="select(fav)" ng-class="favClass(fav)" class="panel-controls panel-controls__item">
   {{fav}}
</div> 

    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("favouriteBtn", function ($scope){

     $scope.fav = ['add', 'added'];
     $scope.selected = $scope.fav[0];

     $scope.select = function(fav) {
        $scope.selected = fav;
      };

    $scope.favClass = function(fav){
      return fav === $scope.selected ? 'active' : underfined;
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a guess:

```
ng-class="{active: fav == selected}"
```

or if you only want to change displaying the button:

```
ng-show="fav == selected"
```

or

```
ng-show="fav != selected"
```

Comment: It works to a certain extend but it doesn't display one state at a time. for example on my demo i have two boxes, I am trying to only display one.

Comment: then you should try ng-show="fav == selected" or  ng-show="fav != selected"

Comment: Thanks, the only question i have regarding this that text only changes i have would like the background color to change also, I have set up and active class to display as green. When i use the ng-show function it displays as none. when i change to display block the active state sits under the unactive state.

Comment: if you have mor to change than only the display you may use the ng-class varinat.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as Michael says.

On the view:

```
<div class="{{selected}}">
  <div ng-show="selected == 'add'">
    <button ng-click="toggleButton()">Button1</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="selected == 'added'">
    <button class='disabled'>Button2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ButtonCtrl',
[
  '$scope',
  function($scope){
    $scope.fav = ['add', 'added'];
    $scope.selected = fav[0];

    $scope.toggleButton = function(){
      $scope.selected = fav[1];
    };
  }
]);
```